# How to check the index of a function in an Array of functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am pretty new level to JavaScript.
I have a function taking `y` as the input to return an array with size `y` which has almost the same functions as the elements.

This is my code:

```
  function createArrayOfFunctions(y) {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<y; i++) {
    arr[i] = function(x) {    
      return x + i);}  //Probably this is the issue
    }
    return arr;
  }

  var input = "5,3,2";

  var [y, n, m] = input.split(",");
  console.log("input = " + input);
  [y, n, m] = [parseInt(y), parseInt(n), parseInt(m)]
  var addArray = createArrayOfFunctions(y);
  console.log(addArray[n](m));  //I would like to add up n and m
```

When I execute the code, the `i` keeps at 5 instead of iterating from 0,1,2,3,4 for arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4]. As a result, it always output `m+y` instead of `n+m`. I have tried to use `indexOF` and `this[i]` to figure out the index of the functions, but it does not work. Is there any ways for me to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clearly say what will be the input and what wil be the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered a scoping issue.

Here is a solution:

```
function createArrayOfFunctions(y) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    arr[i] = function(x) {
      return x + i;
    };
  }
  return arr;
}
```

The above uses `let`, which scopes the `i` variable to each loop iteration.

If you can't use `let` due to compatibility, use an IIFE for each loop:

```
function createArrayOfFunctions(y) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    (function() {
        var _i = i;
        arr[_i] = function(x) {
          return x + _i;
        };
    })();
  }
  return arr;
}
```

The above code caches each `i` variable for each loop in an IIFE, which keeps it in scope.

Comment: Can you please explain what you changed and why? That will help the OP and readers